# Google Geocode API - 403 Forbidden Error from unit test, but not in browser

Tags: c#, google-maps

The following C# code keeps returning a 403:Forbidden during DownloadString. I am running the code in a unit test on my laptop. When I paste the URL into a browser, both Chrome and IE, it works. Also, when I remove the clientID, sensor, and signature, it works fine.

I've tried many variants of adding headers, SecurityProtocol, etc, to no avail.

The URL looks like:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=440+Sauve+Cres&components=locality:Waterloo|administrative_area:ON&client=##clientID##&sensor=false&signature=##signature##

Where ##clientID## and ##signature## are internal company values.

```
    protected virtual string SendRequest(string url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(url);
        string response = null;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            //client.Headers.Add("User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
            client.Headers.Add("Host", "maps.googleapis.com");
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            response = client.DownloadString(url);
            Console.WriteLine(">>>" + response);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Using httpfox, which works, I see the following:

## Request Headers

- (Request-Line)    GET /maps/api/geocode/xml?address=440+Sauve+Cres&components=locality:Waterloo|administrative_area:ON&client=##clientID##&sensor=false&signature=##signature##= HTTP/1.1
- Host  maps.googleapis.com
- User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
- Accept    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
- Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.5
- Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
- Connection    keep-alive

## Response Headers

- (Status-Line) HTTP/2.0 200 OK
- access-control-allow-origin   *
- Alternate-Protocol    443:quic,p=1
- Cache-Control public, max-age=86400
- Content-Encoding  gzip
- Content-Length    510
- Content-Type  application/xml; charset=UTF-8
- Date  Tue, 07 Jul 2015 19:55:41 GMT
- Expires   Wed, 08 Jul 2015 19:55:41 GMT
- Server    mafe
- Vary  Accept-Language
- X-Frame-Options   SAMEORIGIN
- X-XSS-Protection  1; mode=block
- X-Firefox-Spdy    h2

No cookies.

In the content tab of httpfox:
Error loading content (NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED)

Comment: Did you track the data exchange in your explorers, what gives you the senddata/postdata parameters and the redirections? _When I have to do that I use httpfox in Firefox_. The problem may be related to cookies and resulting of indirections.

Comment: I tried httpfox. No cookies, and I do not see any redirects.

Comment: Try to change your code with 2 params in Add method, i;e. : client.Headers.Add("User-Agent","Moz...

Comment: No luck with 2 params. Code updated.